# i can't see the animation by using matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 100
x = np.random.randn(n)
```

I could not be able to see the animation of this code. Can anyone help me?

```
#function
def update(curr):

    if curr == n: 
        a.event_source.stop()


    #graphs
    plt.cla()
    bins = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.5)
    plt.hist(x[:curr], bins=bins)
    plt.axis([-4,4,0,30])
    plt.gca().set_title('Sampling the Normal Distribution')
    plt.gca().set_ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.gca().set_xlabel('Value')
    plt.annotate('n = {}'.format(curr), [3,27])

fig = plt.figure()
#animation
a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)
```

Comment: you probably need `plt.ion()` which should enable animations ...  maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the #function def update(curr): so I was writing a long answer on how to use the FuncAnimation method but I think all you need to do is add: `plt.show()`
after `a = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=100)`